# updating multiple charts with one focus chart using Angular nvd3 directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

I am trying to create a dashboard where everything is controlled by one focus chart.

For example, if you check out the plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/waXnb57OKA9vkrZzNtrm?p=preview then you will see a "nvd3-line-with-focus-chart" on top and a "nvd3-cumulative-line-chart" on bottom.

```
 <nvd3-line-with-focus-chart
          data="exampleData"
          id="exampleId"
          width="400"
          height="300"
          height2="50"
          x="xFunction()" 
          y="yFunction()"
          forceY="[0]"
          interactive="true"
          tooltipcontent="toolTipContentFunction()">
            <svg></svg>
        </nvd3-line-with-focus-chart>

 <nvd3-cumulative-line-chart data="exampleData"
                id="exampleChart2"
                showXAxis="true"
                showYAxis="true"
                tooltips="true"
                interactive="true"
                margin="{left:80,top:10,bottom:30,right:50}"
                isArea="true"
                tooltip="true"
                x="xFunction()"
                y="yFunction()">
        </nvd3-cumulative-line-chart>
```

I'm wondering how I can update the "nvd3-cumulative-line-chart" with the selected range based on the first focus chart ("nvd3-line-with-focus-chart")?

Also, with the current angularjs-nvd3-directives library, is it possible to display only the focus chart on the first display?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi Jason, did you find a solution to your problem ? I'm also trying to use one focus for two charts.